# count the number of elements in list of matrices and return it based on a condition

Tags: r

Suppose that I have a list of matrices. I would like to count how many values for each corresponding position. For example, there are two matrices. The number of values at the position `[2,1]` is only one value. However, at the position `[3,1]` there are two values.

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00    0
[2,] 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00    0
[3,] 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00    0
[4,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.00    0
[5,] 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.00    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00    0
[2,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00    0
[3,] 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00    0
[4,] 0.25 0.5 0.25  0.00    0
[5,] 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25    0
```

**What I expected**

I would like to count the number of values at each position. For example, how many values at position `[3,1]`. The count is across the matrices. That is, if I have `10` matrices, then how many values at position `[3,1]` across all the matrices. In my example, there are only two matrices and the number of values at `[3,1]` is two.

For each position, if the count is equal `1` (the output is = `1`) then return it as it. However, if the count output is `>` `1` then the subtract it by `1`. That is, suppose this:

`outcount = 10` ## the output at the position `[1,3]`. Then, return it as this: `newcount = outcount -1`.

Any help, please? I am thinking about `count`, however, I do not know how to achieve it.

Comment: Not clear about your expected output.  Please update.  `Reduce('+', lapply(l, '!=', 0))`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You said `there are only two matrices and the number of values at [3, 1] are two`  Wouldn't it needs to be subtracted by 1?

Comment: Yes. The number of values is two and the return must be `1`.

Comment: Please check the solution I posted.  Based on your description, it should be working for you

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we are counting the number of non-zero values, we loop through the `list`, convert the `matrix`es to `logical` and `Reduce` by getting the `sum`

```
out <- Reduce('+', lapply(l, '!=', 0))
i1 <- out > 1
out[i1] <- out[i1] - 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I did not mean the sum. I mean counting the number of values across the matrices.

Comment: @F.AMER  Yes, that is what it is doing.  When you sum 2 TRUE values, it becomes 2

Comment: Ok. I see now. I will apply it and see.

Comment: @F.AMER  I just updated my post based on your second condition i.e. if the number of non-zero elements are greater than 1, then subtract 1